# linqpad won't show exceptions?

Tags: linqpad

I'm using the latest linqpad version  : (under 4.5.1)

But when I run this code :

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        list.ForEach(i =>
        {               
            if (i < 3) { list.Add(i+1); } 
        });
```

I don't get an exception where if I run it under VS-2013, I do get an exception.

[image]

**Question.**

It is not throwing an exception. Any reason why? How can I fix it to throw an exception?

Comment: Which exception does VS throw? Just tested your snippet in LinqPad and Vs2013. Run flawlessly both times.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because, even though Linqpad is running under 4.5.1, it may be compiling code targeted for Framework 4.0. If you change VS2013 to target framework 4.0 it will probably behave the same as Linqpad. (I know this is the opposite of what you really want).